# Driver not supporting OpenGL in application build with Go and Fyne on MSYS2

Tags: go, msys2, mingw32, fyne

I am trying to build an simple application with Go and [Fyne](https://pkg.go.dev/fyne.io/fyne/v2) on MSYS2-MINGW32. The `go build` command  completes without any error, but when I run the application, I get following error:

```
2022/10/22 08:08:14 Fyne error:  window creation error
2022/10/22 08:08:14   Cause: APIUnavailable: WGL: The driver does not appear to support OpenGL
2022/10/22 08:08:14   At: C:/Users/iuser/go/pkg/mod/fyne.io/fyne@v1.4.3/internal/driver/glfw/window.go:1220
```

How can this problem be solved?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what sort of computer you are running. First try updating your graphics driver. The OpenGL required is 13 years old so you should not have a problem of it not being supported.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using virtualmachines you need to enable 3d acceleration.

In Oracle VirtualBox, you must:

- Select your VIrtual Machine
- Go to Settings
- Go to Display
- Set Video Memory to greater than or equal to 16 MB
- Check "Enable 3D Acceleration

Answer (score 0):

Видимо графический процессор не поддерживает fyne.
Скачайте последний релиз здесь - https://github.com/pal1000/mesa-dist-win/releases
Assets --> mesa3d-23.1.9-release-msvc.7z (смотря какая там будет версия) После скачивания этого файла разархивируйте и запустите systemwidedeploy.cmd
Затем нажмите 1 (первый пункт)

Всё заработает!

**English translation using Google Translate:**
Apparently the GPU doesn't support fyne. Download the latest release here - https://github.com/pal1000/mesa-dist-win/releases Assets --> mesa3d-23.1.9-release-msvc.7z (depending on what version it is) After downloading this file, unzip and run systemwidedeploy.cmd Then press 1 (first item)

Everything will work!

Comment: Please translate it to English.

Comment: I have added English translation above.